# VB.NET 2015 How to call an external Python program from Visual Basic Program

Tags: python, vb.net

I am trying to run a compiled Python Program File *.pyc from within Visual Basic 2015 program button click method

```
    Dim OpenCMD
    OpenCMD = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    OpenCMD.run("C:\WinPython\CODES\python runnow.pyc")
```

This throws the below error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in 
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

When I run the same command in command line using cmd.exe it runs successfully

```
python runnow.pyc
```

Please help me to run the python program from VB.NET 2015 I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 edition.

Many thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Comment: Is there a reason for creating a `wscript.shell` COM object instead of using the .NET Framework's [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) method? The former is how you would do it in earlier versions of VB, but you tagged this as VB.NET and should embrace the newer methods whenever you can.

Comment: Same Error as below using your suggestion **Process.Start("C:\WinPython\CODES\python C:\WinPython\CODES\resumekeywords.pyc")** Do you have a suggestion as it is not finding the path to the python file I guess?

Comment: Typically when using the `Process` class, you specify your arguments in a second, separate string parameter (see the [`Process.Start(String, String)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically). Try doing it that way. Another thing to check is whether your PATH environment variable contains any strings with quotes in them, since the [documentation states that could cause a FileNotFoundException to be raised](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx#Exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, none of the suggested Answers above worked. So I had to create a batch file and put the command in the batch file:

```
OpenCMD.run("C:\WinPython\CODES\runnow.bat")
```

Batch file:

```
python runnow.pyc
```

The above works like a charm and gives the necessary output required.

Comment: I had a similar problem and sorted it with the batch file you may want to do it dev null though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem might be at this line:

```
OpenCMD.run("C:\WinPython\CODES\python runnow.pyc")
```

...since you indicated that simply running `python runnow.pyc` in cmd.exe works as expected.

Try specifying the full path to your `runnow.pyc` file in your `OpenCMD.run` call. I'm guessing it can't find the file because it is not in your Python executable's working directory when that method is called.

Comment: Nope does not work same error I gave the following command: **OpenCMD.run("C:\WinPython\CODES\python C:\WinPython\CODES\runnow.pyc")** @christopher-kyle-horton

Comment: @PuneetMathur Well, it was worth a shot. Thanks for letting us know. See my other comment posted in response to your last comment on the question itself above.